# Your app contains non-public API usage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to submit my app to the AppStore but I'm getting this msg:

Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the erros, correct them, and resubmit your application.

```
The app contais or inherits from non-public classes in Payload/iPark.app/City-6AEFBE8F8D9CC569.o: City
```

I only use google Maps api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're saying you have a class called `City` and it conflicts with the name of one of Apple's private classes. Right click on `City` in `City.h` and select refactor and prefix the name with your initials. For example, I would name mine `JLCity`.

Comment: +1. As a standard practice, you should do this for *all* of your classes in an iOS project. (In fact, Apple has apparently started to recommend that you [use three initials for each class-name prefix](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW12).)

Comment: City Apparently is a part of Apple's maps api.